# TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly/ grocery list

Tags: python-3.x

I am having an issue combining a float variable into my print string. I am very new to coding and I need help with this problem

I have tried converting everywhere I know how and have been stuck here for awhile

'''
The task is broken down into three sections.
Section 1 - User Input
Section 2 - loop through the grocery list
Section 3 - provide output to the console
'''

#Task: Create the empty data structure

```
grocery_item = {}

grocery_history = []
```

#Variable used to check if the while loop condition is met

```
stop = True 

while stop == True:
```

## Accept input of the name of the grocery item purchased.

item_name = input('Item name:\n'.

## Accept input of the quantity of the grocery item purchased.

quantity = input('Quantity purchased:\n')

## Accept input of the cost of the grocery item input (this is a per-item cost).

```
 cost = input('Price per item:\n')
```

## Using the update function to create a dictionary entry which contains the name, number and price entered by the user.

```
 grocery_item = {'name' : item_name, 'number' : int(quantity), 'price' : float(cost)}
```

## Add the grocery_item to the grocery_history list using the append function

```
grocery_history.append(grocery_item)
```

## Accept input from the user asking if they have finished entering grocery items.

```
choice = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' for quit:\n")
if choice == 'c':
  stop = True
else:
  stop = False
```

## Define variable to hold grand total called 'grand_total'

```
 grand_total = 0
```

## Define a 'for' loop.

```
for i in grocery_history:
```

## Calculate the total cost for the grocery_item.

```
item_total = grocery_item['number'] * grocery_item['price']
```

## Add the item_total to the grand_total

```
grand_total += item_total
```

## Output the information for the grocery item to match this

## 2 apple    @   $1.49   ea  $2.98

```
print(str(grocery_item['number']) + grocery_item['name'] + " @ " + str(grocery_item['price']) + " ea "+ item_total)
```

## Set the item_total equal to 0

```
item_total = 0
```

## Print the grand total

```
print(grand_total)
```

I just keep getting this error over and over 
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly

Comment: Please try to fix your code. I tried adjusting the formatting, but it's missing end braces and stuff. Also post the exact error with trace.

Comment: It looks like `item_total` is a number and needs to be wrapped in a call to `str` though.

Answer (score 0):

```
grocery_item = {}
grocery_history = []
stop = True 

while stop == True:
    item_name = input('Item name:\n')
    quantity = input('Quantity purchased:\n')
    cost = input('Price per item:\n')
    grocery_item = {'name' : item_name, 'number' : int(quantity), 'price' : float(cost)}
    grocery_history.append(grocery_item)
    choice = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' for quit:\n")
    if choice == 'c':
        stop = True
    else:
        stop = False
    grand_total = 0
    for i in grocery_history:
        item_total = grocery_item['number'] * grocery_item['price']
        grand_total += item_total
        print(str(grocery_item['number']) + grocery_item['name'] + " @ " + str(grocery_item['price']) + " ea "+ str(item_total))
        item_total = 0
        print(grand_total)
```

and the output is:

```
Item name:
apple
Quantity purchased:
2
Price per item:
1.49
Would you like to enter another item?
Type 'c' for continue or 'q' for quit:
q
2apple @ 1.49 ea 2.98
2.98
```